# Best way to tokenize names

Tags: python, string, tokenize

Say you have a string that contains names, as follows:

```
"Leonard, A., Fraternali, F., Daraio, C."
```

Now, there are three people in this string, and I would like to find the best way to obtain these three people, given that the string could also be sometimes:

```
"Leonard A., Fraternali F., Daraio C.",
```

i.e., without the commas. Before I had a function as follows:

```
def tokenize(str, token=','):
    return [x for x in re.split(r'\s*%s\s*' % token,str) if x]
```

But of course this doesn't work in the first case.
Thanks!

Comment: How many names are there in this string? `"Jefferson Blythe III, William, Bush, George W."` I would consider this to be a task you can't really automate properly with that format.

Comment: What is the format of the names? Is there any structure to the list (like always Surname followed by initial of first name)?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will do

```
In [10]: re.split(r'\.,', "Leonard A., Fraternali F., Daraio C.")
Out[10]: ['Leonard A', ' Fraternali F', ' Daraio C.']

In [11]: re.split(r'\.,', "Leonard, A., Fraternali, F., Daraio, C.")
Out[11]: ['Leonard, A', ' Fraternali, F', ' Daraio, C.']
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
def tokenize(line, token=','):
    splitline = line.split(token)
    names = []
    for name in splitline:
        name = name.strip()
        if len(name.replace(".", "") ) == 1:
            try:
                names[-1] = '%s %s' % (names[-1], name)
                continue
            except IndexError:
                pass
        names.append(name)
    return names


In: tokenize("Leonard A., Fraternali F., Daraio C.")
Out: ['Leonard A.', 'Fraternali F.', 'Daraio C.']

In: tokenize("Leonard, A., Fraternali, F., Daraio, C.")
Out: ['Leonard A.', 'Fraternali F.', 'Daraio C.']
```

Comment: This doesn't work. In the case that there are people with two names it fails:

    >>> tokenize("Pal, R.K., Awasthi, A.P., Geubelle, P.H.")
    ['Pal', 'R.K.', 'Awasthi', 'A.P.', 'Geubelle', 'P.H.']

Comment: Well it did work for the string you gave above. Try replacing `if len(name.replace(".", "") ) == 1` with `if '.' in name` ...

Answer (score 0):

OK, if your names all end up with a dot `.`, then this would work:

```
>>> names = "Leonard A., Fraternali F., Daraio C.".split('.')
>>> names
>>> ['Leonard A', ', Fraternali F', ', Daraio C', '']
>>> names = [name.strip(', ') for name in names if name]
>>> names
['Leonard A', 'Fraternali F', 'Daraio C']
```